# Is there a Linux CLI tool for determining a partition's "used" space? (like gparted)

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted

I'm shrinking a Linux SDCard partition using AOakley's awesome guide. I'm trying to automate it, but there appears to be no command-line tool for determining the number of bytes in a partition that are used.

For example, gparted tells me the used space is 1.88GB out of 6.99GB (note, I'm using /dev/loop0 which is mounted to the second partition of /dev/sdb):

`df` is wrong:

```
% df /dev/loop0
Filesystem  ... Use%
udev        ... 0%
```

...and `fdisk` and `parted` don't print used space.

What can I use from the command-line to determine the used space in a partition the way `gparted` does?

ANSWER: Summary from below: The partition is `ext4` which allows me to use `dumpe2fs` and extract: `free blocks`, `block count` (total), and `block size` which can be combined to exactly match `gparted`. Turns out that `resize2fs` handles fragmentation during the shrink. See the manpage for `ext4` for more info (although the manpage editor is a tad bitter about GiB vs. GB! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df` is almost the right tool but you should query the mountpoint (or any file below) that belongs to the filesystem you want to examine, not the device node. The node you used, `/dev/loop0`, is a special file that belongs to the `udev` virtual filesystem; hence you got `udev`.

Mount `/dev/loop0` (or `/dev/sdb2`, I'm not sure why the need for `/dev/loop0`) somewhere (it can be `ro` mount) and invoke `df /the/mountpoint`. Then `df` will tell you what the filesystem reports about itself.

I said "`df` is *almost* the right tool" because there is no guarantee you can shrink the filesystem (and later the partition) to the size reported by the tool. What `df` prints can be your first (or rather zeroth) estimate.

You need different tools to resize different fielsystems. In a perfect world such tool (or some accompanying tool) is able to tell you the minimum possible size, or at least the minimum size for which resizing will succeed for sure. In reality you can encounter this:

> Known Bugs
>   The minimum size of the filesystem as estimated by `resize2fs` may be incorrect, especially for filesystems with 1k and 2k blocksizes.

<sup>([source](https://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs))</sup>

`gparted` uses filesystem-specific tools. I did run it with `strace` and saw no evidence it uses `df`. I saw `btrfs filesystem show …`, `dumpe2fs …`, …

Summary:

- You used `df` in the wrong way.
- It's better to use a tool specific to the filesystem anyway; `gparted` does. I cannot tell you what tool you should use because you haven't specified the filesystem in question.

Comment: Ah, good point: I see the correct usage when I mount the second partition's /dev/loop0 to a mount-point. It's an 'ext4' partition. I'm not sure how fragementation works on ext4 filesystems, so I'm suspicious that `df` is reporting the boundary around all used space, holes included. I forgot all about `strace`, I'll look into that and see what gparted is calling for this partition. Not sure what the family of ext4 tools are called (googling now!). Thanks for the push in the right direction!

Comment: Looks like dumpe2fs has inode/fragment/block info, just need to learn about it unless you know an easy way to parse that file?